# Angular tabulator click event not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tabulator

I create table from HTML template

```
<div class="model-params" *ngIf="isModelParamsAvailable">
        <div
          class="model-params--item"
          *ngFor="let param of getParams(task, 'model')"
          (click)="addToParamsSortingList(param.key, 'model')"
           pTooltip="Add/Remove to sorting list"
           [class.active]="isParamListIncludesParam(param.key)">
          {{ param.key }}: {{ param.value | json }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

In function i just console params:

```
public addToParamsSortingList(key: string, type: string): void {
  console.log('test', key, type);
}
```

But (click) event not firing, i can't use cellClick callback because i render data by ngFor, please help me. I cant find answer, how to provide (click) event into tabulator HTML template

Comment: check console for errors?

Comment: @DeepakJha Console clear